# Explicit bijection between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Any idea of an explicit bijection between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$? Even if I think of rational elements as $\frac {m}{n}$, sending them to $(m,n)$ won't work, because all pairs $(m,0)$ don't have a source...

Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: That's the smallest problem. The bigger problem with that is that $\frac ab=\frac cd$ happens frequently for different pairs $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$.

Comment: and 4/2=2/1 so its not a bijection

Comment: does it have to be Z, not $Z^+$ or something, or $\mathbb{Z-{0}}$

Comment: Well.. fix enumerations (bijections) $a:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q$  and $b:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ and consider $ab^{-1}$..

Comment: Hint; find out about the [Schroeder-Bernstein theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schröder–Bernstein_theorem).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a not so popular but explicit bijection from $\Bbb Q^+$ to $\Bbb N$.

http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/countRats.shtml

Say you have **the positive rational number** $t=m/n$
where m and n are relatively prime.

Say m and n have the following prime number decompositions:
$m = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_r^{a_r}$
$n = q_1^{b_1}q_2^{b_2}...q_s^{b_s}$

Then you map $t$ to this **positive integer**:

$p_1^{2a_1}p_2^{2a_2}...p_r^{2a_r} q_1^{2b_1-1}q_2^{2b_2-1}...q_s^{2b_s-1}$

1) Prove that it's a bijection.
2) This can be easily modified to accommodate also
negative rationals and the rational zero. How?

Comment: I misread your question, you want Q mapped to ZxZ, I see now. I'll leave this post here just because it's an interesting technique.

Comment: Haven't you heard? People love to downvote answers that they think don't directly answer the question, regardless of the validity of the content.  I'm just telling you because it happened to me (twice! here!).

Comment: @user46944 I know, I guess it's normal. It's OK, I don't care so much about my rating.

Comment: Well, with my comment it can give a full answer.

Comment: @Berci Feel free, I don't see it yet. Not sure about the N->ZxZ bijection. I'll explain my not seeing it just with the late hour ;)